# How could I add fire-like lighting to Rivendell?

Tags: set-modification, lighting

I'd love to add lights to the Rivendell set to improve the look of the displayed model in low light.

[image: Rivendell set photo]

Ideally, the lights would provide a flame-like effect where appropriate.

What is the best way to do this using official LEGO parts?

Answer (score 21):

Here's a still photo showing the final look that I came up with:

[image: Rivendell Illuminated]

Here's an animation attempting to capture the subtle flame effect:

[image: Overall with flicker animation]

### Parts

I've used 3 [City Powered Up hubs (28738)](https://rebrickable.com/parts/28738/hub-battery-box-powered-up/) in this modification:

[image: Powered Up Hub]

I used 5 [Powered Up lights (88005-1)](https://rebrickable.com/sets/88005-1/light/?inventory=1#parts) connected to those hubs:

[image: Powered Up Light]

I also used a few very common parts to make minor modifications to the model and secure the lights.

### Modifications

This set is composed of three distinct sections that can be moved independently. I chose to maintain this independence for easy portability.

#### Left Section

From left to right, the first section is the tower and the bedroom. I chose the hide the battery box where the bookshelf would have been in the lower room:

[image: Left battery]

The hub itself provides a modest amount of light on the lower level and drives an LED in the roof of the bedroom:

[image: Bedroom light]

The second LED on that pair snakes up to the top of the tower:

[image: Tower light part 1]

[image: Tower light part 2]

[image: Tower light part 3]

#### Center Section

For the center section, I chose to hide the battery box in the roof. I found that it fits quite nicely once it gets wiggled into position:

[image: Center battery box]

One pair of LEDs is used to light the main section. I've attached them via 1x2 Technic bricks in the rafters above the shards of Narsil:

[image: Shards of Narsil Lights]

The second set of lights from this hub are split up. One goes to the small tower:

[image: Center tower light]

The other light is hidden in roof of the small structure jutting out from the main hall:

[image: Center front light]

#### Right Section

One pair of lights is used under the bridge to accent the water. These are affixed to a pair of 1x2 Technic bricks placed under the bridge:

[image: Bridge Lights]

The second set of lights are split up. One provides general moonlight-like illuminate for the gazebo:

[image: Gazebo Light]

The final light is placed behind the fire for the forge. It is attached to a Technic brick that replaced the black panel behind the fire in the original build:

[image: Forge Light]

### Software

I wanted to use the City Hubs for this project, as they are relatively small, widely available, and most compatible with System building. Unfortunately, these hubs can't be used without a constant connection to a smart device using the default firmware.

This limitation can be overcome using [Pybricks](https://pybricks.com/). I wrote some basic code to the hub that would turn on any attached lights without the need for a smart device. From there, it is fairly straightforward to add a flickering algorithm.

While I was making things more complicated, I figured that it also made sense to leverage the RGB LED built into the hubs. I set this to also flicker in a nice orange hue. The [code](https://github.com/jncraton/bricklights/blob/main/examples/cityflames.py) for all of this is available on Github if its useful to anyone.

I like the final look of the flickering quite well. Here's my attempt to capture it again:

[image: Overall with flicker animation]

### Final Model

Here are few shots from various parts of the model showing off the lighting:

[image: Forge]

[image: Gazeebo with Aragorn and Arwen]

[image: Boromir and the shards of Narsil]

[image: Frodo with Gandalf]

Comment: That's nicely done.  I saw something quite interesting about flickering a while back, but I can't find it now.  One thing that's interesting is that a flame that goes steady (after flickering) gets whiter as well as brighter. I played with flame flickering on a Arduino - it was quite effective but I don't seem to have uploaded the code anywhere.  You could simulate different fires flickering separately, but also a breeze causing them to behave in sync